# What is the difference between an instance and an object in Python?

Tags: python, class, object, instance

I know that this question has been asked and answered many times but the answers to those questions aren't really assuaging. Each person has given a different definition of both which is really confusing. Being a novice, I really don't know whom to trust. Can someone please clarify the difference between them?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Link the posts and articles you've read and explain what you took away from them and what you didn't understand. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. See also: [ask]

Comment: [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) differentiates between `instance objects` and `method objects`.  Could it be the source of your confusion>

Answer (score 3):

In Python, *everything* is an object.  Moreover in Python objects are instances of classes, so it follows that every object is also an instance of some class<sup>*</sup>.

However, we generally use the term *instance* in preference to *object* when we want to discuss the behaviour of instances of a specific class or classes

> Instances of `Foo` provide the following operations ...
>
> No two instances of `Bar` may compare as equal ...

So we might say that object is the most general term, whereas instances refers to the set of objects which are instances of a particular class or classes, and instance to a specific object which is an instance of a particular class.

In short, they are the same thing, but we use these terms in different contexts.

<sup>*</sup>Python enables this circular definition by making `object` an instance of `type`, and `type` an instance of `object`, and both `object` and `type` are instances of themselves.

Comment: Would it be fair to say, then, that instance refers to a relationship, while object does not?

Comment: You're right I think, it's implicit, isn't it?  Feel  free to edit if you want to improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

*instance* and *object* are effectively the same thing. When you create an instance of a class, that instance is an object.

Put another way, every instance is an object. That is the literal definition of an object: an *instance* of a class.

Comment: I don't agree. Yes, instances are objects. But not all objects are instances. Essentially everything in python is an object, even the class itself.

Comment: @JohanSchiff do you have an example of an object that is _not_, ultimately, an instance of a class?

Comment: A class or a method?

Comment: @JohanSchiff a class is an instance of its Metaclass, a method is an instance of `types.FunctionType` or `types.MethodType`, depending on whether it's bound to an instance.

Comment: @JohanSchiff: classes are also objects.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I guess you're right then. How about a metaclass or a module? Also, you generally don't see people referring to classes as instances, and I think most programmers would find that quite confusing. So maybe it's advisable, even if it's true, not to refer to classes as instances?

Comment: @JohanSchiff I suppose we generally use instance in relation to a particular class, as, as you say, in most contexts the fact that all objects are also instances is not a particularly observation.  A different story wit metaprogramming though.  Anyway, we are mostly in agreement I think; cheers!

Comment: @snakecharmerb Now tell me with *absolute clarity*, what is the difference between an ```instance``` and an ```object```? It would be better if you write an answer.

Comment: @NirajRaut: Every instance is an object.

Comment: @Brian Oakley Is every ```object``` an ```instance```?

Comment: @NirajRaut: yes. By definition, an object is an instance of a class.